# What does "walk out" mean here?

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does "walk out" mean here?

“I wish we could just split the tab using a simple app on our phone, and just walk out like Uber” others will say. http://techcrunch.com/2014/12/24/the-greasy-underpan-of-restaurant-tech/

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/walk+out
Obviously, both definitions are not applied here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe they want to each pay their individual part of a tab which encompasses both of their meals electronically, without the need to use a physical credit card, and/or interact with a teller or cashier. Presumably the idea of leaving cash on the table, with the difference in the check amount and the cash amount standing in for a formal tip, then "walking out", isn't an option or hadn't occurred to them.

Comment: Thanx, but I still can't understand how this is like Uber?

Comment: Just edited, but basically with uber you never have to handle cash or interact with your driver if you don't want to. you just go where you're going, tap the screen a couple times, make sure its correct, nod and get out.

Comment: Now I got it) thanx